# Como deixar minha WebView reiniciar automático a cada 30 m

Tags: java, android

Queria saber como deixar minha página reiniciando automaticamente a cada 30 minutos em segundo plano. Quem puder ajudar, agradeço.

```
Public class tela2 extends AppCompatActivity implementa tela2 {

private Timer t;
private int TimeCounter = 0;
WebView xp1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela2);

    xp1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.xp1);
    xp1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    xp1.setFocusable(true);
    xp1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    xp1.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    xp1.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    xp1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    xp1.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    xp1.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    xp1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    xp1.loadUrl("http://pt.clubcooee.com/client/start");
    xp1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("pegando xp");
}
public  void  startTimer()
{
    t= new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // CODIGO A SER EXECULTADO EM SEGUNDO PLANO A CADA 30 MINUTOS

                }
            });
        }
    },18000000,18000000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer executar alguma coisa em segundo plano, devemos usar os serviços(Service) do Android.

```
public class UpdatePageService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Para iniciar um serviço, coloque essa linha de código na sua Activity. Pode ser no onCreate, por exemplo.

```
startService(new Intent(this, UpdatePageService.class));
```

Para agendar uma tarefa de tempos em tempos, é recomendado o uso do AlarmManager. O AlarmManager tem vários jeitos de ser implementado dependendo das APIs do Android que seu app irá abranger.

Um exemplo de um serviço com AlarmManager:

```
public class UpdatePageService extends Service {
    private AlarmManager alarmManagerUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        configureAlarmRefreshPage();
    }

    private void configureAlarmRefreshPage(){
        Calendar alarmHour = Calendar.getInstance();
        //configura alarmHour com hora atual
        alarmHour.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //adiciona 30 minutos com base na hora atual
        alarmHour.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmHour.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 30);

        alarmManagerUpdate = (AlarmManager) getContext().
                          getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //verifica a versão do Android para configurar com o método adequado
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {                 
            alarmManagerUpdate.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.
            RTC_WAKEUP, alarmHour.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent operation);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManagerUpdate.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            alarmHour.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent operation);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
            alarmManagerUpdate.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
            alarmHour.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent operation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // cancelar todos os alarmes
    }
}
```

No terceiro parâmetro da configuração de alarmManagerUpdate.set(), você precisa passar uma PendingIntent. A PendingIntent vai te informar quando o alarmManagerUpdate estiver no tempo de atualizar a página. A implementação da PendingIntent depende do jeito que você deseja obter o aviso do alarme.

[Documentação PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Observação importante: Seja cuidadoso com a implementação de um AlarmManager, pois se implementado de maneira incorreta, pode minimizar a duração da bateria.

[Aqui tem alguns exemplos de implementações com PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)